# UIButton - call Release only when no pending events?

Tags: iphone, events, uibutton, queue

I have a UIButton. When I tap on the button I want to redraw my view with different buttons (only some of the buttons change so I don't need an entirely different view).

What I'm finding is that the touch event, highlight and unhighlight events are all queued. As a result, when I release my button, these events try to execute on the released object resulting in my app crashing - so I must be calling Release too soon.

How can I call Release only when pending events/messages for an object such as as UIButton have all been processed? (e.g. something like "[myButton ReleaseWhenNoPendingEvents];")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by implementing ARC.